# autoprefixer - how to exclude IE

Tags: css, autoprefixer

my project manager does not want to support IE at all, so I'm wondering whether my config is correct:

`last 2 versions, not ie <= 11`

as it does not change anything in the output when i omit `not ie <= 11`.
Do I have to explicitly name all browsers I want to support instead?
I understand, it does not hurt to have some extra prefixes, on the other hand, I don't believe it won't help IE users that much if the page is just "partially broken"

Comment: Where are you adding that config? In `.browserlist.rc`, or somewhere else?

Comment: `package.json` and it works with no problems, e.g. changed to `last 1 chrome version` and `-moz` prefixes were gone